# Laravel how to replace a words in string

Tags: laravel, string, str-replace

I am trying to change words in string, I know laravel Str::replace() function but it converts if you write exact word. This is what i want to do :

$string = " this is **@username** and this is **@username2**"

I want to find usernames which starts with "**@**" and make them like below, i want to add `<strong>` html tag them :

$newstring = " this is `<strong>@username</strong>` and this is `<strong>@username2</strong>`"

I couldnt find the way to change dynamic value on str replace.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `preg_replace`

```
$string = 'this is @username and this is @username2';

$newString = preg_replace('/(\@\w+)/', '<strong>$1</strong>', $string);
```

> Docs: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php